# Is WaitForSingleObjectEx allowed to wake up early?

Tags: winapi, synchronization

I'm sumbling over a case where WaitForSingleObjectEx with a timeout on an event is not returning "signalled", yet the timeout has not passed.

Specifically, to debug this issue in Qt, I changed [this code](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/thread/qmutex_win.cpp?h=5.6#n41):

```
bool QMutexPrivate::wait(int timeout)
{
    return (WaitForSingleObjectEx(event, timeout < 0 ? INFINITE : timeout, FALSE) == WAIT_OBJECT_0);
}
```

to this code (which includes measurements):

```
bool QMutexPrivate::wait(int timeout)
{
    LARGE_INTEGER StartingTime, EndingTime, ElapsedMicroseconds;
    LARGE_INTEGER Frequency;

    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&Frequency);
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&StartingTime);

    auto result = (WaitForSingleObjectEx(event, timeout < 0 ? INFINITE : timeout, FALSE) == WAIT_OBJECT_0);

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&EndingTime);
    ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart = EndingTime.QuadPart - StartingTime.QuadPart;

    ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart *= 1000000;
    ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart /= Frequency.QuadPart;
    if (!result && timeout > 0)
        std::cerr << "Waited for " << ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart << " microseconds when asked " << timeout << std::endl;
    return result;
}
```

where `event` is created via `CreateEvent(0, FALSE, FALSE, 0);`.

Stressing this code path prints statements like:

```
Waited for 96734 microseconds when asked for 100 msecs
```

Is WaitForSingleObjectEx allowed to wake early, that is, before the specified timeout (due to timer coalescence in the kernel or similar technologies), or should I investigate my problem elsewhere? The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms687036(v=vs.85).aspx) does not help me clarifying this.

Comment: You are jumping to conclusions too quickly. `result` could be false for any number of reasons, not just a timeout.

Comment: Well, it is actually returning `WAIT_TIMEOUT` (by debugging in the code). The `== WAIT_OBJECT_0` check was there from before. I guess it could be made stronger.

Comment: Is `event` the handle to an actual Windows Event object or to some other synchronization object?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: as I wrote in the post, it's returned by `CreateEvent`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSDN on [Wait Functions and Time-out Intervals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687069(v=vs.85).aspx#waitfunctionsandtime-outintervals):

> The accuracy of the specified time-out interval depends on the resolution of the system clock. The system clock "ticks" at a constant rate. If the time-out interval is less than the resolution of the system clock, **the wait may time out in less than the specified length of time**. If the time-out interval is greater than one tick but less than two, the wait can be anywhere between one and two ticks, and so on.
>
> To increase the accuracy of the time-out interval for the wait functions, call the timeGetDevCaps function to determine the supported minimum timer resolution and the timeBeginPeriod function to set the timer resolution to its minimum. Use caution when calling timeBeginPeriod, as frequent calls can significantly affect the system clock, system power usage, and the scheduler. If you call timeBeginPeriod, call it one time early in the application and be sure to call the timeEndPeriod function at the very end of the application.